# Can I add a Vue single file component to an existing application without using WebPack?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vue.js, webpack

I would like to introduce Vue to an existing ASP.NET MVC app. If we intend to use Vue’s single file components, will we need to add WebPack to the build process?

Currently, our application uses ASP.NET bundles but does no additional compiling/processing of Javascript or CSS. I am trying to understand how adding Vue (or any front-end Javascript framework) will impact the build process.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use [Single File Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html) then you would need a build tool like Webpack. Check out the [deployment guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/deployment.html) for more info on that.

If you want to include it with a script tag and use normal HTML and JS([without build tools](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/deployment.html#Without-Build-Tools) - also the deployment guide) then that should work without changing the build process. I haven't tested it with Razor templates(`.cshtml`), and the [`v-on` shorthand](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#v-on-Shorthand) might cause some issues there.

I'm looking to do the exact same thing right now, and I'm thinking the best way to get started is with the script tag, but I'm a big fan of the single file components

**Edit:** Just confirmed that everything is pretty good in Razor templates except the `v-on` shorthand, so if you avoid that it should be fine.

The following worked in a `.cshtml` file:

```
<!-- Don't do `@click`! Use `v-on:click` instead -->
<div id="vueApp" v-on:click="alert(message)">
  {{ message }}
  <ul>
    <li :title="item" v-for="item in itemList">{{ item }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<script>
  let vueApp = new Vue({
    el: '#vueApp',
    data: {
      message: 'Hello!',
      itemList: ['1', '2', '3']
    },
    methods: {
      alert (msg) {
        // got an error using `alert` in the template, but this was fine
        window.alert(msg)
      }
    }
  })
</script>
```

**Update**: Thanks to [Simon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/617948/simon) for pointing out that you can use `@@click="..."` inside a `.cshtml` file!

Comment: I assume the issue is the @ which razor uses as its 'wake word'. I assume @@click="" would work?